# Multi-line graph does not matches the required result in d3js

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am new in d3.js.I made the multiline plot

[image]

Using this code file

```
import {
  select,
  csv,
  scaleLinear,
  scaleTime,
  scaleOrdinal,
  extent,
  axisLeft,
  scaleBand ,
  axisBottom,
  line,
  curveBasis,
  nest,
  schemeCategory10,
  timeFormat,
  descending
} from 'd3';

import { colorLegend } from './colorLegend';
const svg = select('svg');

const width = +svg.attr('width');
const height = +svg.attr('height');

const render = data => {
  const title='Profit Comparision by Segment by Region'
 // Region,Sub_Category,Profit
  const xValue = d => d.Sub_Category;
  const xAxisLabel="Sub-Category"

  const yValue = d => d.Profit;
  const circleRadius = 6;
  const yAxisLabel="Profit"
  var barPadding = 0.2;
  const colorValue = d => d.Region;

  const margin = { top: 60, right: 160, bottom: 128, left: 105 };
  const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  /*const xScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain(extent(data, xValue))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .nice();*/
 var xScale = d3.scalePoint().domain(data.map(xValue))
  .range([0, innerWidth]);
 /* var xScale = scaleOrdinal().domain(extent(data, xValue))
  .range([0, innerWidth]);*/
  const yScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain(extent(data, yValue))
    .range([innerHeight, 0])
    .nice();

  const colorScale = scaleOrdinal(schemeCategory10);

  const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickSize(-innerHeight)
    .tickPadding(15);

  const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale)
    .tickSize(-innerWidth)
    .tickPadding(10);

  const yAxisG = g.append('g').call(yAxis);
  yAxisG.selectAll('.domain').remove();

  yAxisG.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'axis-label')
      .attr('y', -60)
      .attr('x', -innerHeight / 2)
      .attr('fill', 'black')
      .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')

      .text(yAxisLabel);

  const xAxisG = g.append('g').call(xAxis)
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${innerHeight})`);

    xAxisG
          .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-65)" 
                });
  xAxisG.select('.domain').remove();

  xAxisG.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'axis-label')
      .attr('y', 110)
      .attr('x', innerWidth / 2)
      .attr('fill', 'black')
      .text(xAxisLabel);

  const lineGenerator = line()
    .x(d => xScale(xValue(d)))
    .y(d => yScale(yValue(d)))
    .curve(curveBasis);

  const lastYValue = d =>
    yValue(d.values[d.values.length - 1]);

  const nested = nest()
    .key(colorValue)
    .entries(data)
    .sort((a, b) =>
      descending(lastYValue(a), lastYValue(b))
    );

  console.log(nested);

  colorScale.domain(nested.map(d => d.key));

  g.selectAll('.line-path').data(nested)
    .enter().append('path')
      .attr('class', 'line-path')
      .attr('d', d => lineGenerator(d.values))
      .attr('stroke', d => colorScale(d.key));

  g.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'title')
      .attr('y', -10)
      .text(title);

  svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(820,121)`)
    .call(colorLegend, {
      colorScale,
      circleRadius: 10,
      spacing: 38,
      textOffset: 20
    });
};


csv('data4.csv')
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(d => {
       // Region,Sub_Category,Profit
        d.Profit = +d.Profit;

    });
    render(data);
  });
```

This multiline plot does not match with the plot actual result on the same data. Here this picture in the actual result on the same data

[image]

How I can make this my multiline plot just like the result. What changes in the code is needed. Here is the link to [vizhub code](https://vizhub.com/princit/0dd32a40d74049ecb7befd7bdffc731c?edit=files&file=index.js)

**Update:**

I filtered and sorted them in alphabetical order and profit sorted in a descending order. But I got a different graph not the required result

[image]

How I can get the required result?

Comment: I can't edit your vizhub code, but I imagine there is a sorting issue: the lines will connect your data points in the order they appear for each series, but since you sort these, they don't match the order of the values in the unsorted scale domain, which is why the ticks aren't in alphabetical order. So your lines go back and forth rather than progressing from tick to subsequent tick, explaining the elliptical loops that you see.

Comment: @ Andrew, see my Update in question